# C++ Header implementing a C# Interface

Tags: c#, c++, header-files

It is possible to generate a C++ header file from a C# interface?

Example:

#### C# Interface:

```
public interface A { 
    void M( ushort u ); 
}
```

#### C++ header:

```
public ref class B : A 
{ 
    void M( unsigned short u ); 
}
```

Returns "Error C3766".

Answer (score 1):

The interface must also be public. Try this instead (note 2nd public keyword):

```
public ref class B : public A { void M( unsigned short u ); }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I tried:

C# Interface: public interface A { void M( ushort u ); }

C++ header: public ref class B : public A { void M( unsigned short u ); }

and it didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't have the public keyword on the interface declaration in C#.

Comment: If I remove the public keyword it doesn't recognize the interface in C++.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. C3766 implies that the interface implementation is missing, so the only other thing I can suggest is to explicitly set M's parameter type to UInt16 in C# and C++. ushort should map fine to unsigned short though.

Comment: Ignore the rest of this. Nobugz is right - you're missing the virtual keyword on the interface implementation. +1 to nobugz

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the virtual keyword.  This compiled as expected:

```
public ref class B : ClassLibrary1::A {
public:
    virtual void M(unsigned short u) {}
};
```

Where ClassLibrary1 was the namespace in which the C# interface declaration was made.